# How would I use type as a "variable"?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

std::vector<std::pair<std::string, [type of the object, entity or banana]>> nep; //[type of the object, entity or banana] is my imaginary type

class Entity
{
private:
    int x;
public:
    Entity(const int x) : x(x) {};
    int GetX() const { return x; };
};

class Banana
{
private:
    int y;
public:
    Banana(const int y) : y(y) {};
    int GetY() const { return y; };
};

[type of the object, entity or banana] CreateObj(std::string name) //Used that imaginary variable here again
{
    for (unsigned short int i = 0; i < nep.size(); i++)
    {
        if (nep.at(i).first == name)
        {
            return [new object with type = nep.at(i).second];
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    nep.push_back({ "ent", Entity });
    nep.push_back({ "banan", Banana });

    CreateObj(banan).GetY();

    std::cin.get();
}
```

[type of the object, entity or banana] is my imaginary variable-type thing. 
What I'd like to do is pass there a class for example, and then using `CreateObj()` function I'd like to create new object of that type and use it.
How can I do that?

Comment: IMHO, if you are trying to create objects on the fly, a static factory (factory design pattern) would be appropriate. You'd represent your types as an `enum class` for type safety rather than strings.

Comment: You can use std::variant, it is designed for those cases. (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: no

Long answer:

You have tools like `std::type_index` and `typeid`, but they won't do what you want.

You can however store factory function instead of a type:

```
using result = std::any; // or some other common type

std::map<std::string, std::function<std::any()>> nep;

nep["banana"] = []{ return Banana{}; };
nep["entity"] = []{ return Entity{}; };

// Call the functions:
result my_banana = nep["banana"]();
Banana& b = std::any_cast<Banana&>(my_banana);
```

The functions stored in the map create instances of a known type. Since the map has to store functions of the same type, it must be returned through a common type. That common type can be `std::any`, `std::variant<Banana, Entity>` or a pointer to a base class.

Then you can search the map for a factory function and call it to get the created object. It must be unwrapped correctly to access the variable through the right type to access members.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to use polymorphism, you can do something with meta-programming:

```
enum class ClassType {
    EntityType,    
    BananaType,
};

namespace internal {

    template <ClassType Type>
    struct _build_type {};

    template <>
    struct _build_type<ClassType::EntityType> {
        constexpr auto operator()() {
            return EntityType();
        }
    };

    template <>
    struct _build_type<ClassType::BananaType> {
        constexpr auto operator()() {
            return BananaType();
        }
    };
}
```

And then, your construct object:

```
template <ClassType Type>
constexpr auto create_instance() {
    return internal::_build_type<Type>{}();
}
```

So you can do:

```
const auto object = create_instance<BananaType>();
```

This thing will increase your compilation time but it does not have any performance penalty during runtime.